# Ε-R diagram with conditions , is it possible?

Tags: database-theory

I want to create a database and model it with an E-R diagram. This database should be about a library. An entity is the member of the library, where the member can borrow books from the library. However , the member cannot borrow more than 5 books and cannot borrow any more books , if he hasn't returned every book of which the time to return it has expired. Ιs it possible to model this condition with an E-R diagram?

Comment: Such conditions cannot be modeled with classical E-R diagrams, that represent structural aspects of the model, but must be expressed as integrity constraints accompanying it.

Comment: @Renzo how would you do that?

Comment: As the comment of Koenig Lear suggests, you can use the UML methodology and tools.

Answer (score 1):

This can be expressed in a one to many relationship with a 0..5 end:

LibraryPatron 1 <----> 0..5 BorrowedBook

Using relational algebra they can be expressed using check constraints as Renzo suggested.   Some ER tools may also allow you to express this as a constraint.

Comment: If I can only use 1:N , N:M and 1:1 , what would you suggest?

Comment: @maverick98 you could use UML notation